# Using Jtidy to parsing HTML

Tags: java, junit

I am using [Jtidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/testcases.html) I pass an `InputSteam` and then I tried to validate whether or not the XHTML code in the InputSteam is valid.

```
InputStream s = new ByteArrayInputStream(my_string).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);

tidy.parse(s, System.out);
```

I would like to validate my test, `true` or `false` instead of printing this to the console: `5 warnings, no errors were found!`

If I get 1 error how do I make my JUnit reflect a fail?

**I noticed that no matter what my string looks like it gets parsed as valid always**
I tried this:

```
String my_string = "TABLE width = 400 &&&& table height = ";
```

That gets parsed as valid without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the last line with something like this:

```
tidy.setErrout(null);
tidy.parse(s, null);
Assert.assertEquals(0,tidy.getParseErrors());
```

Comment: `tidy.parse(s, null);` Gives me this compiler error: **The method parse(InputStream, OutputStream) is ambiguous for the type Tidy**.   How can I fix it? Also `Assert` is depricated.

Comment: Try using a cast.  Or use a StringWriter instead of null.  I assume you can figure out the assertion part on your own.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question/problem.
This is how I solved it:

```
String validHtml = "some valid html";
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(validHtml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXmlTags(true);

tidy.parse(inputStream, null);

System.out.println("errors "+tidy.getParseErrors());
System.out.println("warnings "+tidy.getParseWarnings());
assertTrue("HTML has errors and it should not.",tidy.getParseErrors()==0);
```

The trick is in `setXMLTags(true)`.